# Fitting a model with bounded data and subsequently retraining it

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning, online-algorithms

I have five independent variables, each of which vary between 0 and 10. The output of from these combinations is multi-class output which is essentially a judgement call by an industry expert. We are planning to have this as our base training set and then subsequently enhancing the model as and when new / actual data starts coming in.

The requirement is that the model train itself quickly with the new data and discard the old learning from the base training set.

My initial thought was to train a linear model with less data and make it a high variance model, and then add the subsequent real data as and when it comes to reduce the variance and make it more tuned to the real data. But I'm not sure if this is the right approach. Is there a better way of approaching this problem?

EDIT: The initial data is by an consultant whereas the new labelled data is by an expert who understands the specific business context. The model is supposed to start out with general predictions and then fine tune itself to make predictions for the specific client.

Comment: What form will the new data coming in have? Will it be unlabelled? Or will you be able to receive it labelled with the correct class - if so, how (e.g. by the expert again, or will the true class be obvious due to other events following correct/incorrect prediction by your model)?

Comment: In addition, you might want to explain more what you intend to do to "make it a high variance model" - making a model high variance (given the same input data) typically means adding more parameters. For a linear model that might mean adding derived features (e.g. add all 15 combinations of multiplied features $x_i \times x_j$ ). But I am not sure if that's what you mean?

Comment: New data will be labelled with the correct by the expert. And I was thinking that high variance could be achieved by training it with very little sample data. So the model would then be very sensitive as and when new real world data keeps coming in.

Comment: If the new data is labelled by the expert, same as initial data, what precisely will be different between the initial data set and the later data? You seem to want to discard the learning from the initial data, but it is not clear why - i.e. what is different about it that you trust the later data to be more accurate or useful?

Comment: The new data is labelled by an on-field expert, who understands his business context. Whereas the initial data is labelled by a consultant who gives a broader, industry perspective. The model is supposed to start out with general predictions and then fine tune itself to make predictions for the specific client.